# Jquery and IE8 issue

Tags: jquery

I have created a select that should change the url page on the select event.

I have wrote this simple script to do that:

```
<select name="elenco_regioni" id="elenco_regioni">
<option value="">Select an option</option>
<option value="http://example.com/page/1">Page 1</option>
<option value="http://example.com/page/2">Page 2</option>
</select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){   
        $('#elenco_regioni').bind('change', function () {
            var url = $(this).val();
            if (url) {
                 window.location = url;
            }
            return false;
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Everything works great on Firefox, safari, chrome, IE9...How can I fix it on IE7 and IE8?

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Have you tried using `window.location.href` or `window.location.assign` instead of `window.location`?

Comment: The problem is that I have another option in the select but it has no value and the IE8 consolle says: can't get the value because the object is null or not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it in a function

```
<select name="elenco_regioni" id="elenco_regioni">
<option value="http://example.com/page/1">Page 1</option>
<option value="http://example.com/page/2">Page 2</option>
</select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){   
        $('#elenco_regioni').bind('change', function () {
            var url = $(this).val();
            if (url) {
                 go_to_url(url);
            }
            return false;
        });
        });
        function go_to_url(url)
        {
             window.location = url;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks but with this script the page doen't work, it doesn't canghe the url anymore

Comment: what is the error? and see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/bgW3K/
it works :)

Comment: I have found the problem, I hope! The problem is that I have another option in the select but it has no value and the IE8 consolle says: can't get the value because the object is null or not defined